# Php mail with Html contents wrong

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

i'm trying to send php email with this codes, but all times html has problems, it seems that php automatically adds `!` after one ore more `<`
for example `<!td` i can't solve this error..

```
     $intestazione.= "<body>";
$intestazione.= "<div style=\"background-color:#ff8400;color:#fff;text-align:center;padding:20px;\">";
$intestazione.= "<h1>TEST</h1><br>";
$intestazione.= "<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"border:0px;width:100%;\">";
$intestazione.= "<tr>";
$intestazione.= "<b>TEST:&nbsp;</b><td>".$V."</td><br>";
$intestazione.= "</tr>";
$intestazione.= "<tr>";
$intestazione.= "<b>TEST:&nbsp;</b><td>".$V1."</td><br>";
$intestazione.= "</tr>";
$intestazione.= "<tr>";
$intestazione.= "<b>TEST:&nbsp;</b><td>".$V2."</td><br>";
$intestazione.= "</tr>";
$intestazione.= "<tr>";
$intestazione.= "<b>TEST:&nbsp;</b><td>".$V3."</td><br>";
$intestazione.= "</tr>";
$intestazione.= "<tr>";
$intestazione.= "<b>TEST:&nbsp;</b><td>".$V4."</td><br>";
$intestazione.= "</tr>";
$intestazione.= "<tr>";
$intestazione.= "<b>TEST:&nbsp;</b><td>".$V5."</td><br>";
$intestazione.= "</tr>";
$intestazione.= "</table><br>";
$intestazione.= "<b>TEST:&nbsp;</b><br><td>".$V6."</td><br>";
$intestazione.= "</div><br>";
$intestazione.= "</table>";
$intestazione.= "<h1>TEST:</h1> ";
$intestazione.= "<table id=\"tabella_pr\" class=\"tabella_pr\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"border:0px;width:100%;text-align: center;\">";
$intestazione.= "<tr><th style=\"width:25%;text-align:left !important;\"><b>OGGETTO</b></th><th style=\"width:25%;\">DESCRZIONE</th><th style=\"width:25%;\">Qta.</th><th style=\"width:25%;\">t</th> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">v4</td><td style=\"text-align:center\">".$v4."</td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$pv4."</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">v5</td><td style=\"text-align:center !important\">".$v5."</td><td></td><td></td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">v6</td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:center\">".$v6."</td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$v6."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">v6</td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:center\">".$v7."</td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$v7."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">c 12</td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:center\">".$c1."</td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$tc1."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">c 22</td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:center\">".$c2."</td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$tc2."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">c 52</td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:center\">".$c3."</td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$tc3."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">c 102</td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:center\">".$c4."</td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$tc4."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">c 202</td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:center\">".$c5."</td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$tc5."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">c 252</td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:center\">".$c6."</td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$tc6."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">c 502</td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:center\">".$c7."</td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$tc7."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">c8</td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:center\">".$c8."</td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$tc8."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">Iff</td><td></td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$ff."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">ffg</td><td></td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$gff."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">Ifgf</td><td></td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$gfg"€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">teacher</td><td></td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$pff."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">dfdf</td><td></td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$fdfd."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\">Tjuynh</td><td></td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:right\">".$rgtg."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\"></td><td></td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:right\"><b>tst </b>".$itrdt."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\"></td><td></td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:right\"><b>Ibvgf  </b>".$vfvvf."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr><tr><td style=\"text-align:left;\"></td><td></td><td></td><td style=\"text-align:right\"><b>vftg  </b>".$tgr."€</td> ";
$intestazione.= "</tr>";
$intestazione.= "</table>";
$intestazione.= "</body>";

$mail_destinatario = "mail@mail.com";

// definisco il subject ed il body della mail
$mail_oggetto = "TEST OBJ";

$mail_headers = "From: " .  $name . " <" .  $mail . ">\r\n";
$mail_headers .= "Reply-To: " .  $mail_m . "\r\n";
$mail_headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
$mail_headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$mail_headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"."\r\n";

if (mail($mail_destinatario, $mail_oggetto, $intestazione.$mail_corpo, $mail_headers))
  echo "ok.";
else
  echo "error";

?>
```

[image]

Comment: change first line $intestazione.= "<body>"; to $intestazione= "<body>";

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Comment: I also would recommend to use a template. Nobody can maintain these things later..

Comment: Screenshot of error helpful as well. I cannot reproduce the error using your code.

Comment: changed first line, but same problem.. @Jalin

Comment: @dom_ahdigital if i inspect the page with google it seems that "<td>" with problems are without "text-align:center" or  "text-align:left"

Comment: @Ajex_12 I think you really need to provide a screenshot example of what you think is wrong. It is not clear from your post or comment. I cannot see anywhere where `<!td` is occuring either in the source or DOM inspector.

Comment: i've added a screenshot @dom_ahdigital

Comment: You're declaring a charset of ISO-8859-1, but then using the € character, which does not exist in that charset. Use UTF-8 or ISO-8859-15.

Comment: changing in "UTF-8" i'm getting this -> "0â! �¬" in only one <td>, others are ok, but still having same problem @Synchro

Comment: you missing '.' in style=\"text-align:right\">".$gfg"€</td> "; line no 46

Comment: @Jalin i''ve added '.' but still having same problem

Comment: x-mailer header is missing "\r\n" suffix.

Comment: @Colin added but still having problems

Comment: What's in $mail_corpo that you're appending to $intestazione? Do you have two body's (since the <body> is specified in $intestazione as well)? Have you tried sending a very simple message and gradually working your way up until you start seeing the problem?

Comment: $mail_corpo is a empty variable now, I removed but same problem.. @Colin

Comment: I would suggest you provide the SO community runnable code that demonstrates the problem in as few lines as possible. (But this is also what you should be doing to debug it yourself anyway so just doing this may reveal the problem you're having.) e.g., if you see the problem even if your $variables aren't in the code, take them out of what you post. If your inline-CSS doesn't affect the problem, take it out. etc. Help people to help you. :-)